# Inegarating Google Analytics and Core Data handling iOS.

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, google-analytics, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Currently I am supporting an iOS Project. Google Analytics V1 code is already added in it. But when I am running app on iPad2 (iOS 7.1),Google analytics is not showing the device. When I checked into device console, I am getting warning:

`dispatch called ...
nothing to dispatch`

So I tried to update code with newer google analytics sdk version but now App is crashing with some exception with CoreData. When I searched for error, I found that it is due to NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification.

So I want to know if I can make it work with Version 1 or how I can resolve Coredata problem with new version of GA.

I am getting error with newer version is:

```
WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.06 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'***

First throw call stack:

```
(0x32cd012 0x2dc2e7e 0x79b4d2 0x79b230 0x77f293 0x77dc86 0x77d1de 0x2dd66b0 0x19dd035 0x3250f3f 0x325096f 0x3273734 0x3272f44 0x3272e1b 0x38e67e3 0x38e6668 0x1d7965c 0x2c2d 0x2b65)
```

`libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: Are you using Core Data directly, or is Google Analytics using it on its own?

Comment: Yes I am using CoreData directly also in my code to maintain a database of downloaded contents of application.